# Can iOS protocols enforce notifications to be implemented?

Tags: ios, notifications, protocols

In this protocol definition, the ios dev page (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/) lists the MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification notification.

My understanding is that the a class adhering to the protocol should implement the properties and methods. But what about the notification? Is it optional?

The Apple help page on protocols (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1) doesn't talk about notifications.

Comment: Notifications are always optional.

Comment: There is not language-level way to specify whether between protocols (and classes as well). Notifications are defined on the level of particular library or framework.